# Is MultiLineString geoJSON feature type supported by mapbox-gl?

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

When i try to add source with MultiLineString to 'line' layer nothing is rendered. No errors, no lines.

After i transformed MultiLineString features into LineString features lines rendered successfully.

Comment: Can you share your geojson data??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `MultiLineString`s are supported by mapbox-gl-js. Here's a working JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/cozudodelo/edit?html,output

I would recommend validating your GeoJSON with a tool like [geojsonhint](https://github.com/mapbox/geojsonhint) to make sure you're not running into missing brackets or something.